Prevent page scrolling when cursor is hovering over element Blazor
In Blazor I have a canvas with Pan/Zoom capabilities made with Excubo Canvas however if the page has enough content to make the page scrollable, scrolling on the canvas to zoom out also scrolls the page down.
I'm using the @onwheel event for the scroll action on the canvas. I've tried adding @onwheel:preventDefault, @onwheel:stopPropagation, and the same for @onscroll and the scrolling persists. I've also tried to set css touch-action: none. Everything still scrolls.
How can I just disable any scrolling over an element?

The preventDefault with onwheel just doesn't work. It is a known issue.
You can use js event handling for that:
 <canvas onwheel=" event.preventDefault()"></canvas>

Working solution here.
